# cannot read property of an incoming json object in form

Tags: angular, http

Made numerous attempts of extracting the value of 'name', which is certainly present, from the get request.

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { FormBuilder } from '@angular/forms';
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';
import { config } from '../../config';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-profile',
  templateUrl: './profile.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./profile.component.css']
})

export class ProfileComponent {

  currentUser: any;
  countries: any;

  constructor( private fb: FormBuilder, private http: HttpClient ) {
    this.http.get<any>(`${config.apiUrl}/api/v1/user/profile`).subscribe(user => this.currentUser = user);
    this.http.get<any>(`${config.apiUrl}/api/v1/service/enum/country/english`).subscribe(x => this.countries = x.success);
  }

  userInfo = this.fb.group({
    success: this.fb.group({
      image: [0],
      name: this.fb.group({
        value: [this.currentUser.success.name.value]
      }),
      middlename: this.fb.group({
        value: ['']
      }),
      surname: this.fb.group({
        value: ['']
      }),
      dayOfBirth: this.fb.group({
        day: [''],
        month: [''],
        year: ['']
      }),
      allegiance: this.fb.group({
        value: ['']
      }),
      gender: this.fb.group({
        value: ['']
      }),
    })
  })

  onSubmit() {
    console.log(this.userInfo.value);
  }
}
```

If I subscribe immediately to the console.log, then it will show the object successfully. But if I write `console.log(this.currentUser)`, then it will show `undefined`.

Is it that I do not understand something about cycles? (the countries do work by the way)

Comment: HttpClient Get calls work asynchronously. Are you calling console.log() before the data has been returned from your server? That would result in undefined.

Comment: I call console.log(this.currentUser) in the constructor (just after the requests). So where would it make sense to stick it?

Comment: Put it in the callback function. `.subscribe(user => {this.currentUser = user; console.log(this.currentUser);});`